# Añadir datos en la primera linea de un csv con php fputcsv()

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

Tengo una interrogante de cómo lograr almacenar estos valores en las primera linea de un csv ejemplo:

```
$id = '1';
$name= 'alfredo';

$file = fopen('demos.csv', 'a');
fputcsv($file, array($id, $name));
fclose($file);
```

Esta parte funciona bien lo malo está en que **1,alfredo** se almacenan en la última celda o linea de csv y lo que busco es que se guarden al inicio de la lista.

Ejemplo:

```
> 1,alfredo 
> 2,juan 
> 3,jon
```

Gracias por su tiempo espero alguna idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien luego de una investigacion aqui tienen la respuestas:

```
//Clave aleatoria
$b = uniqid();
// Nombre de archivo
$a = 'demos.csv';
// Datos a escribir
$id = $b;
$name= 'alfredo';
// Lee todo el archivo y lo carga a un vector
$data = file($a,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
// Agrega el dato al vector
array_unshift($data, "$id,$name,$b");
// Abre el archivo para escritura, truncando el contenido
$file = fopen($a, 'w');
// recorre el vector y reescribe todo el archivo
foreach($data as $l){
  fwrite($file,$l.PHP_EOL);

}
fclose($file);
```

Saludes espero que a otra persona le resulte de utilidad

Answer (score -1):

¡Hola! Lo único que se me ocurre por ahora es que recrees el archivo. Vale decir, abres el que ya tienes con los datos previos, lo lees y lo almacenas en un array en memoria, cierras el link al archivo, luego en el array recién llenado le agregas la primera fila de la que hablas, para entonces pisar el archivo original con el nuevo array de datos... Es una sugerencia.

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia . Pero no es una manera muy logica de intentarlo Gracias

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions Oki. Igual busqué por la red una solución distinta a la mía, algo como más nativo del lenguaje, pero me topé con la misma idea en otros foros... seguro hay otras soluciones, suerte ;)

Comment: Bien gracias seguire buscando una solucion logica . y luego respondere esta pregunta